# How to make a random password that doesn't start with "-", "_", or "0"?

Tags: javascript

```
function randomPassword() {
    let length = 15,
        password = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_",
        space = "";
    for (let i = 0, mu = password.length; i < length; ++i) {
        space += password.charAt(Math.random() * mu)
    }
    return space;
}

console.log(randomPassword());
```

I'm new at javascript. I finally made this code but i don't want it to create a password that starts with "-", "_", "0". How can i do that?

Comment: Make a 14-characters password and then attach at the beginning a random entry from `password`, excluding `-` and `_`

Comment: You can either loop until it doesn't start with your characters, or just create a subset that doesn't contain the unwanted characters, and in place of initializing `space` with `""` you can initialize it with a random character of that subset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We keep the `_`, `-` and `0` away from the character string while we generate the first character for the password. After generating the first character, we add the `_`, `-` and `0` back to the character string and generate the rest of the characters for the password.

```js
function randomPassword() {
    let length = 15;
    
    // Initial characters without -, _ or 0
    let characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
    
    // Generate first character
    let password = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length + 1));
    
    // Add the symbols now
    characters += "-_0";
    
    let n = characters.length;
    
    // Generate rest
    for (let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        password += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    
    // Return
    return password;
}

console.log(randomPassword());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be something like this :

```
function generatePassword() {
  var length = 15,
    charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_",
    retVal = "";
  for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
    let charOne = charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    if (i == 0) {
      while (charOne == "-" || charOne == "_" || charOne == "0")
        charOne = charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    retVal += charOne
  }
  return retVal;
}
console.log(generatePassword())
```

https://jsfiddle.net/40fa5neo/

Comment: Aren't we doing potentially a lot of unnecessary looping here?

Comment: @Swiffy my code is slightly faster than yours https://jsfiddle.net/wgkzr0x8/

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting. Weird...